# Last Skype versions on Windows & iOS without excessive large ads

Tags: windows, ios, chat, communication, skype

I am looking for the last clean Skype versions on Windows & iOS that did not have the bad UI with excessive large banner & poster advertisements.

I know I can try to go to OldApps and get an old version and try to stick with it for a while, but need to know the version number of the last good versions of the Skype on Windows desktop & iOS.

Comment: Just a thought: by using an old version of Skype you are open to security
vulnerabities that have been fixed in newer versions. Is it worth it?

Comment: @mguassa - Anything which is that critical or required for security, I'd prefer to use something other than ugly new skype

Answer (score 1):

Conversation advertisements and worsened UI came after Microsoft acquired Skype on 2011-05-11.

Conversation advertisements were [announced on 2012-06-13](http://blogs.skype.com/2012/06/13/skype-advertising-update/), so you should try Skype 6.3.0.105 or earlier from 
http://www.oldapps.com/skype.php

I'm not sure whether older versions can still connect though. I used to use older versions of Skype (ante-Microsoft) for the same two reasons (mostly UI, there may be some other way if only the ads are an issue) but I stopped using it a while ago.

Comment: Thank you :) That side does not have the old versions or earlier that you specified. I have been googling around but the sources I find so far seem to be a little funky & may contain trojans/ viruses/ cant be trusted completely.

Comment: @AlexS Wow no way... I used to use this site to get old Skype version, I wonder why they removed it.

Comment: Probably Microsoft & their Copyrights.. Do you have a copy or can point to a location with a safe/ clean copy of that version or its portable version?